# Lua table library removed?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to learn the ropes on Lua, and I was going through the online tutorials. One problem I tried to solve was to examine a table `local foo = {}` to see how many elements it had. The tutorial gave the suggestion to use `local length = table.getn(foo)`. When i try this using Lua52, I get an error stating `attempt to call field 'getn' (a nil value)`. I looked around further and noticed that any of the functions given with `table` produce the same type of error. Was the `table` library removed from Lua? Is it a third-party library, or what gives?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the length operator `#` as in `#foo`.

`table.getn` was deprecated in 5.1 and removed in 5.2.

Comment: The first hit for "lua size of array" is [this obviously horribly outdated book](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html) advocating `table.getn`. And thats on `lua.org`.

Answer (score 5):

The table library wasn't removed, as it's an essential part of the language and the module system. The `getn` function was removed but if *none* of the table functions work, it's almost certainly because you've overwritten `table`.